# Hide 'Dropdown' select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good afternoon, do you know if there is any way to hide the 'Dropdown' that appears with the options of a select when clicking on it? When click add a class to an element to show a hidden div but for something less than 1 sec you see the dropdown.

If you can help me, I would be grateful

A greeting.

```
$('.select').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).attr("disabled", true);
   $('.options_select').addClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain more, what you really want to achieve? Is it an option to disable the dropdown upfront, so you can't even click it?

Comment: I want that when clicking on the select, a hidden DIV appears but I do not want the dropdown to be displayed with the options, since the options are in that hidden DIV

Comment: Sounds like you want to render a custom dropdown. There are some limited options to style options of a select. Maybe this fits your needs (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp). Otherwise it's easier to replace the select with hidden input and create your own dropdown element with `divs`, `ul` and `li`.

Answer (score 0):

No,  is a *replaced element*, that is rendered by the operating system. There is no CSS option to hide the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

There's some notes on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Styling_with_CSS
I think you can get what you're looking for like this: https://codepen.io/gerard-payne/pen/NVjppd

```css
select {
    appearance: textfield;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

option {
  display: none;
}
```

but also setting disabled and adding a font color.

```html
<select disabled="disabled">
    <option>2000</option>
    <option>2001</option>
    <option>2002</option>
</select>
```

```css
select[disabled="disabled"] {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't add the options to the list or add something like:

CSS:

```
 .select > option {
       display: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".select").on('click',function(){
$('.submenu').toggle();
})
```

```css
.select{ border:solid 1px #000; display:inline-block; padding:20px; cursor:pointer;}
.submenu{ background:#345; display:none;}
.submenu a{color:#fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">Select</div>
<div class="submenu">
<a href="#">option</a>
<a href="#">option</a>
<a href="#">option</a>
<a href="#">option</a>
</div>
```

i think you want this? if not let me know